# Codeigniter 3 - Query Builder 'join' Method Issue - Records Repeating

Tags: codeigniter, join, inner-join, codeigniter-3, query-builder

**Not a Duplicate Question!!!**

---

I am using **CodeIgniter 3 - Query Builder Class** with **MySQLi**.

---

### Tables in DB:

'**category_level_1**'  Table:
[image]

'**category_level_2**' Table:
[image]

---

### Query in model.php:

```
$query = $this->db
  ->select('category_level_1.id, category_level_1.category')
  ->from('category_level_1')
  ->join('category_level_2', 'category_level_2.cat_lvl1_id = category_level_1.id', 'inner')
  ->get();
```

---

### Output :

[image]

 Values are repeated.

---

### Expected Output :

[image]

---

### Issue:

As showed above, output values are repeated according to **'inner' join**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

You should add `group_by` in your query to get the desired result

```
$query = $this->db
  ->select('category_level_1.id, category_level_1.category')
  ->from('category_level_1')
  ->join('category_level_2', 'category_level_2.cat_lvl1_id = category_level_1.id', 'inner')
  ->group_by('category_level_1.id')
  ->get();
  /*print_r($query->result());*/
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: add group_by to this query to get the desired result . see my  answer